# iOS Notifications in Background

Tags: ios, notifications

I am currently developing an app which, on launch, pings a server which returns a unique identifier for each device connecting. The device retrieves another page from the server every 5 seconds for a different set of data. This unique ID can be plugged into a web interface which alters a value returned to the phone. On the next update, the app sees the change and sends a notification to the user.

I want the process from after the assignment of the unique ID to be able to work without the app having to be open. Could I have it run in the background and use something like a local notification to alert the user to a change in the data?

I'm really tired, right now, so sorry if I made any typography errors... just ask me to clarify anything you need. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not. You set the localNotification when your app is running and you cant change it or create new  localNotification when your app id down as the iphone os is in charge to fire it and not your app so you can not do that.

You can if it helps you, send remote notifications as the value changes in the server and then handle the app behavior after the user gets the notification.